# Getting code completion on __callStatic() in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, code-completion

I have got the following class:

```
/**
 * @method MyObject a()
 */
class MyClass {
    /**
     * @return MyObject
     */
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments = NULL)
    {
        return new MyObject($name);
    }
}
```

On Netbeans when I write `MyClass::a()` I will get code completion on `MyObject`. However, this only works thanks to the `@method MyObject a()` comment on the class. But my `__callStatic()` method handles *every* possible method name. I would like to be able to write `MyClass::something()` and then get code completion on the `MyObject`. Is there any way to get that code completion without listing *every* possible method name in the PHPDoc? Is there some kind of place holder like `*()`?

Side question: How does Eclipse handle this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not. You have to add a `@method` tag for every name. Same thing goes with `__get()` and the `@property` tag. This is true as of Netbeans 7.0.1. Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) with PDT works the same way and requires `@method` tags in this situation as well.

Comment: in Eclipse 3.7 +PDT the `@method` tag doesn't provide code-completion for *static* methods

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sad that there was no other. I'll probably use a workaround function which just returns the new object instead until there is a real solution. Also, I created an [enhancement request](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=205057) on the Netbeans bug repository. Interested users are welcome to vote to increase its priority :)